# AVCaptureVideoDataOutput on iPhone 3G?

Tags: iphone, avfoundation

Does the iPhone 3G supports the functions of the AVCaptureVideoDataOutput class? Or is it limited cause of the lack of the video feature?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, it runs on 4.0 and higher. Here's some (buggy) Apple sample code [AVCam](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html) to run and play with. Also, if you're thinking of making something serious, here's a nice post explaining what's [wrong](http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/ios4-take-photos-with-live-video-preview-using-avfoundation/) and can be done better and simpler with AVFoundation framework.